# C++ WebSocket Server Implementation (Accept Key missmatch)

Tags: c++, websocket

I tried searching but didnt find any answears.
I'm making a websocket server in c++, but I can't get the accept-key to work.

here is my code:

```
std::string magicKey = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
key.append(magicKey);   
unsigned char* sha_str = SHA1(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(key.c_str()), key.length(), nullptr);
std::string final = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(sha_str), strlen((char*)sha_str));
```

And I'm using the openssl/sha.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you concatenating "=" at the end?

equalant perl code is to verify if you need

```
    use Digest::SHA qw(sha1_base64);
    my $clientKey="xyz";
    my $specifcationGUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
    my $fullWebSocketKey = "$clientKey$specifcationGUID";

    # dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11
    #print "Fill socket key is $fullWebSocketKey\n";
    # 0xb3 0x7a 0x4f 0x2c 0xc0 0x62 0x4f 0x16 0x90 0xf6 0x46 0x06 0xcf 
    # 0x38 0x59 0x45 0xb2 0xbe 0xc4 0xea
    print sha1_base64($fullWebSocketKey) . "=";
```

Comment: But after the sha1 and base64 it already got the "=" at the end. It need to get 2 of them??

Comment: try comparing the final string in your code with the perl one , they should be the same

Comment: Also please check the length of the sha1 string should be 20. strlen(str) could be an issue also.

Comment: So the sha_str should got 20 length? so if the strlen((char*)sha_str) dont return 20 its wrong?

Comment: well it is always 20 bytes and possibly could have 0 value which causes the strlen to return less than 20 length. You can safely use 20 instead of strlen(sha_str).

Comment: Tried that out, but still the same.
And I got a server in C# that works, and the keys are just the same, cant figure out why wont work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25226/discussion-between-adnan-akbar-and-caio-keto)

Comment: So, i was getting with the '/n' at the end of the key, so i removed it and worked.